# Ideal way to implement an article series / multipart blog post

Tags: python, sql, django

I am in the process of writing a blogging engine in django, primarily as an educational exercise and I am wondering about implementing multi-part blog posts / series.

I am working in python3/django so my code will be thus, though I'm mostly concerned with implementing the database structure properly.  Given this generic model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(255)
    content = models.TextField()
```

My first idea is to simply add a series table and link it to the article:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(255)
    content = models.TextField()
    series = models.ForeignKey('Series')


class Series(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(255)
```

The issue that comes up next here is how to track the posts position and series length (ie: 2 of 4). I thought about using the series entry id's, or the post publish dates, though I can't guarantee that those will go in the same order as the posts.

I could simply keep track of that on the article table. Then I can just use the .count() on the series objects for the series length, and get the article position directly from the field: which just doesn't seem to be as elegant as it could be:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(255)
    content = models.TextField()
    series = models.ForeignKey('Series')
    part = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Then I thought about making a third table who's rows will each reflect an article in a series:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(255)
    content = models.TextField()

class Series(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(255)

class ArticleSeriesEntry(models.Model):
    article = models.OneToOneField('Article', related_name='series_info')
    series = models.ForeignKey('Series', related_name='entries')
    part = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I'd ultimately like to be abled to just access the information somewhat like this:

```
{% if article.series is not None %}
    This post as part {{?}} in a {{?}} part series titled {{?}}
    View previous post {{?}}, view next post {{}}
{% endif %}
```

I feel like there's got to be a better way.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with only two models is sufficient. The third model - `ArticleSeriesEntry` doesn't really serve any purpose. So, I'd ditch that.

Regarding how to get the next or previous posts in the series, I'd create two methods on the `Article` model to do just that:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # ... other fields ...
    part = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def prev_part(self):
        try:
            prev_part = Article.objects.get(series=self.series, part=self.part-1)
        except Article.DoesNotExist:
            prev_part = None
        return prev_part

    def next_part(self):
        try:
            next_part = Article.objects.get(series=self.series, part=self.part+1)
        except Article.DoesNotExist:
            next_part = None
        return next_part

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # this should return url for the given article
        # see docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url
        pass
```

Then in the templates:

```
{% if article.series %}
    This post is part {{ article.part }} in a {{ article.series.article_set.count }} part series titled {{ article.series.title }}

    {% if article.prev_part %}
        View previous post: <a href="{{ article.prev_part.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article.prev_part.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if article.next_part %}
        View next post: <a href="{{ article.next_part.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article.next_part.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```